# use CocoaPods install ZBarSDK (1.3.1) error

Tags: ios, xcode5.1, zbar-sdk

User CocoaPods install ZBarSDK have error
error : directory not found for option '-L/Users/Tank/Desktop/人宇數位科技/MetroNews/MetroNews/ZBarSDK'
I need help.
I need scanning  QRCode in iOS 6.0 and later.
I need armv7s because i install AFNetworking .it need armv7s. so don't delete armv7s.

Answer (score 1):

It should be working now, possibly since December 2014:

Use latest [CocoaPods](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods) and add this line to your Podfile:

```
pod 'ZBarSDK', '~> 1.3.1'
```

Then, run the classic `pod install`. It will build fine, including for armv7s and arm64.

Answer (score 0):

In this moment the great qr/bar code reader library ZBar doesn't work on iPhone 5 simply because no one has re-compiled the library for armv7, and if you try to use this lib in you armv7s ready ios project you obtain linker error.

**Your solution is here:**

https://web.archive.org/web/20170128181158/http://www.federicocappelli.net/2012/10/05/zbar-library-for-iphone-5-armv7s/

which links to:

[Linker Error in Xcode 5 for libzbar.a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740304/linker-error-in-xcode-5-for-libzbar-a/18937831#18937831)

Comment: I key hg clone http://zbar.hg.sourceforge.net:8000/hgroot/zbar/zbar in my commands. It error : -bash: hg: command not found...
why?

Comment: If you want to run hg (Mercurial) from the commandline, you'll have to download it from http://mercurial.selenic.com/downloads/ and install it.