# Validation error for iPhone app using ZBar SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, zbar-sdk, zbar

I have an iPhone app (for iOS 7 & above) which uses the ZBar SDK. I'm struggling to update it for iOS 7 using Xcode 5.1.1.

I was getting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140492/zbar-with-ios7-and-xcode5-compiling-error-libzbar-a-architecture?rq=1) arm64 build error, but I've managed to fix that by recompiling libzbar.a according to the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740304/linker-error-in-xcode-5/18937831#18937831).

The app now archives successfully. However, when I try to validate it in the Xcode Organizer I get the following error: "This bundle is invalid. Apps that include an arm64 architecture are required to include both armv7 and armv7s architectures."

I have "Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s, arm64)" set for my project's Architectures and "arm64 armv7 armv7s" for the Valid Architectures.

I not sure what else to try at the moment, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find anything that would solve this problem. After going around in circles for several days, I removed every trace of the ZBar SDK from my app and instead used Apple's AVFoundation for QRCode support. This option was not available prior to iOS 7, but now that it is life becomes a whole lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

Unplugging my iOS device and re-archiving the build helped me.